# Visual Studio Code - Autoformat / Reformat Indentation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code. How can I change the number of spaces when I have a statement like the following:

if ($flag -eq $true)
{
Write-Host "Hello"
}

So before the Write-Host I want it to indent four spaces.

Plus if a a reformat document adjust it to four spaces.

Where are the options in the settings for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What you need an extension called "Prettier".

You can easily download it in VSCode on the left side in the section called "Extensions" (recommended way to do it).

Also, you can get it from here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode